# Lookup with multipe matches and sum result

Tags: google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nViYZ49mc8xYF7POhddgqaKNjE1E469sfXEkCzZowrI/edit#gid=1559668304

At sheet Data, for example, A has 1 dependant from Jan - Dec and A has another dependant from Jun - Dec, so I want to look up the information at Data, sum it then put into Sheet 1.

Column D is the result that I calculate manually.

Any help.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this formula is cell D2 of Sheet 1, and copy down as many rows as necessary.

`=query(Data!$A$2:$D$4,"select sum(D) where A matches'" &B2& "' and B<= "&A2&" and C>="&A2&" group by A label sum(D) '' ")`